# How can I automate multiple language background images using sass

Tags: css, internationalization, sass

This is the desired CSS:

```
    body[lang=en] .my-div {background-image:url('my-image-en.png')}
    body[lang=de] .my-div {background-image:url('my-image-de.png')}
    body[lang=fr] .my-div {background-image:url('my-image-fr.png')}
    ...
```

I want to automate this process using a mixin like this:

```
body {
  .my-div {
     @include i18n-background-image('my-image')
  }
}
```

Now, I'm close to the solution using this mixin:

```
$languages = ["en", "de", "fr", ...];    
@mixin i18n-background-image($name) {   
      @each $lang in $languages {
        background-image: url(#{$name}-#{$lang}.png)
      }
    }
```

**BUT MY PROBLEM IS** that I can't add the `body[lang=#{$lang}]` because it is already nested inside it. I can find a hacky solution and not nest the classes, but that's not nice - and I want to achieve a clean & readable mixin. Is there a way to solve it? Perhaps iterating in a loop on all the nested classes?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `html[lang=en]` instead of body?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the standard practice but the question remains the same whether the lang is assigned to the html or to the body

Comment: I'm quite sure the `lang` attribute is assigned to the `html`-tag. ;) But yes, the question stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really want to try overqualifying whenever possible.  This should do the job:

```
$languages: en, de, fr;    
@mixin i18n-background-image($name) {   
  @each $lang in $languages {
    &:lang(#{$lang}) {
      background-image: url(#{$name}-#{$lang}.png);
    }
  }
}

.my-div {
   @include i18n-background-image('my-image');
}
```

Output:

```
.my-div:lang(en) {
  background-image: url(my-image-en.png);
}
.my-div:lang(de) {
  background-image: url(my-image-de.png);
}
.my-div:lang(fr) {
  background-image: url(my-image-fr.png);
}
```

> A significant difference between :lang and the other methods is that it recognizes the language of the content of an element even if the language is declared outside the element in question.

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang